# Second derivative always positive or zero in this case?

Tags: calculus

My book says:

> If $f$ is differentiable and difference quotients overestimate the slope of $f$ at $x=a$ for all $h>0$, then $f ' '(x)$ or the second derivative is $\geq 0$ on $[a, h]$.

But if I draw $f(x)$ like this:[image]

then I've just disproven the statement because the concavity on the interval [a, h] is negative sometimes (there are 2 hills). Btw, to the very left of the number line that is a zero not an "O".

Comment: I think you are right. The statement in the book is not correct.

Comment: No special comment about value of $h$?

Comment: Nope just what is in the statement given

Comment: It has to be for all $h>0$, if you pick $h$ between the hills your example is not valid.

Comment: @Alfredo sorry could you explain more I feel like I'm missing something important

Comment: your example in not differentiable, since you have two different slopes at $a$. I would think that @Alfredo means that at the lower points of the valleys the difference quotients would be underestimates. Try to repeat your picture, but instead of straight lines use two curves, the top concave up, the bottom concave down, that have a common tangent line at $a$, and then try to insert a wiggle in between these two curves, as you tried in your original picture, and see that sometimes you would have an overestimate, sometimes an underestimate. Perhaps it should say $f'(a)\ge0$?

Comment: @user532874 In the proposition you have "... slope of $f$ at $x=a$ FOR ALL $h>0$, then $f′′(x)$ ..." The "for all $h>0$" is the important part. In your example is true that the curve doesn't have its second derivate greater or equal to zero, but it is not fulfilling the proposition hypothesis since it says for all $h$ and you are just showing that there is a $h$ that fulfills the hypothesis. If you take other $h>0$ (for example the $h$ with $f(h)$ the valley  of the hills) the proposition doesn't fulfill, so your example is not valid since it doesn't happen for every $h>0$.

Comment: @Alfredo I just realized that the interval $[a, h]$ is a typo in the book and that they meant to say $[a, a+h]$. With that said, for all points (on the curve I had drawn) to the right of $a$, the average slope between the two points overestimates the instantaneous slope at $a$ so my example does meet the *for all $h>0$* requirement.

Comment: @user532874 You are absolutely right, sorry, english is not my first language and I misunderstood the proposition. Then as Kavi said, it is probably wrong.